# Lumen Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::terminating() error in view return View::make('home', ['post' => $post]) in docker

Tags: php, docker, lumen

when im running my lumen apps without docker, everything running as expected. But, when i use docker, and trying to visit the view, It return error as i mention.
with title:

```php
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::terminating()
```

```php
Facade::__callStatic('make', array('home', array('post' => object(Collection))))
in /src/app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php (line 194)
```

my project code snippet is as below:

```php
// im already include facades/view here

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
...

    public function blogViews()
    {
        $post = Post::all();
        return View::make('home', ['post' => $post]);//this is the line 194
    }
```

my composer.json file

```json
...
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "flipbox/lumen-generator": "^9.1",
        "illuminate/session": "^9.35",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^9.0",
        "pelmered/fake-car": "^1.7"
    },
...
```

Also, Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1.5-fpm

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# copy all of the file in folder to /src
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
RUN composer update

#start docker service
CMD php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

please tell me if you also need my `docker-compose` too

Comment: Bug introduced in upgrade from Lumen 9.1.2 to 9.1.3
Downgrading / pinning to 9.1.2 will help until a fix is released by laravel/lumen team

Comment: Bug seems to have been fixed in V 9.1.4
https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/pull/1253/files